# Updating angular datasource from another component makes angular data table pagination not working

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

In my ComponentA I am getting data needed for angular data table from service and store it in a variable datasource which I created in service itself

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
this.service.data = this.service.GetDataFromService();

this.service.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<this.service.data>
this.service.datasource.paginator = this.paginator;

<mat-table [dataSource]="this.service.datasource">

</mat-table>
```

User can click on edit row on datatable and a form(ComponentB) will be opened which user can change the data for that row... I want to refresh datatables data right after from been closed.... data updated but it makes pagination stop working

I do this in ComponentB when user submits the form

```
this.service.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<data>
this.service.datasource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

This time this.paginator became undefined, tried somany ways to not mess up with pagination when data source being refreshed but nothing worked...
Any advice is highly appriciated

Comment: Could you put your code on StackBlitz so that we can take a look?

Comment: the code you have written is a mess we cannot define var inside class but inside function

use a public access specifier and access your data source from service into your any component which has service injected note => service you inject should also be public and not private

Comment: My bad, you right @SyedKhizaruddin ,  I corrected my code.....
infact only issue I have is the paginator, when 
 this.service.datasource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.paginator is undefined...if u can give me a hint why its undefined that would be very helpfull.... 
I do the same thing in ComponentA but its not undefined and pagination works fine

Answer (score 0):

***shared.service.ts*** =>

```
@Injectable({ providedIn:'root' })
export class SharedService{
   commonDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<YourDataArrayInterface>(yourDataArray);

   // your data array data type array
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];

}
```

***componentA.component.ts***

```
import { SharedService } from './path_to_sharedService';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ComponentA {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sharedService.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

***componentA.component.html***

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="sharedService.commonDataSource">
   <!-- rest of your table content -->
</table>
```

***componentB.component.ts***

```
import { SharedService } from './path_to_sharedService';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ComponentB {  
  constructor(
    public sharedService: SharedService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ){}
  dataTableForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
   this.initForm();
  }
  
  initForm(){
    this.dataTableForm = this.fb.group({
      ... your formControls
    });
  }


  onSubmitForm(){
    if(this.dataTableForm.valid){
        // based on your data you have changed change the array of service here
    } else {
      this.dataTableForm.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }
```

***componentB.component.html***

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="sharedService.commonDataSource">
   <!-- rest of your table content -->
</table>
```

Comment: @Seyed CompnentB is a form which updates the datatables data in ComponentA....

Comment: @CodeGoorila i have made the changes you can see now and mark my answer  further solving your problem means spoon feeding you please do necessary changes now as per your need

Comment: @Seyed I dont have mat-table in my ComponentB, ComponentB i only an input form in order to change the rows in table from ComponentA...That means users can click on row on table in ComponentA, Form (ComponentB) will popup and user can change the data for that row.... On Submit that form data for table on ComponentA must be refreshed which Im doing currently but pagintor stops working

Comment: when you set the value from your onsubmit function like ```dataSource = yourEditedArray``` in next line you must update ```dataSource.paginator = this.paginator```

Comment: If u check my question that is what I do, but this.paginator in submit from ComponentB in undefinded and that makes paginator stop working

Comment: paginator initialization is possible where you are using it that means in componentA,

from componentB you cannot access paginator or else you need to use observable after submitting the componentB so that you can use that observable to subscribe to changes in componentA and update the paginator value after edit... or you can send edited value from componentB and update it through observable on componentA @CodeGoorila